# Why is $(r_1 + r_2) \log_2(r_1 + r_2) \leq r_1 \log_2(2r_1) + r_2 \log_2(2r_2)$ for all $r_1, r_2 \geq 1$

Tags: inequality

[image: Problem source]
I'm following along [*A Graduate Course in
Applied Cryptography*](http://toc.cryptobook.us/book.pdf) by Boneh and Shoup, and I don't see where this inequality comes from on page 204. I could follow every step of the proof except this final inequality. This "simple fact" is not readily apparent to me. For context, we know that $r = r_1 + r_2$ which implies $r \log_2 r = (r_1 + r_2)\log_2(r_1 + r_2)$.

The only fact that stands out to me is that the right hand side can be simplified to
\begin{align*}
r_1\log_2(2r_1) + r_2\log_2(2r_2) &= r_1 \log_2(2) + r_1 \log_2(r_1) + r_2 \log_2(2) + r_2 \log_2(r_2) \\
&= r_1 + r_2 + r_1 \log_2(r_1) + r_2 \log_2(r_2)
\end{align*}
Otherwise, I am at a complete lost on getting closer to the desired inequality. Fixing $r_2$ and plotting the functions as a function of $r_1$ convinced me this inequality is probably true, but I have no clue how to rigorous prove its validity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the fact that the function $f(x)=x\log_2x$ from $\mathbb R_{>0}$ to $\mathbb R$ is convex, since the written inequality is
$$f(r_1+r_2)\leq \frac{f(2r_1)+f(2r_2)}2.$$
For a twice-differentiable function like $f(x)$, the easiest way to check convexity is to check that $f''(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$. This holds since
$$f''(x)=\frac1{x\ln 2}.$$

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling utilizing convexity was probably the way to prove the inequality. I hadn't thought about using $f(x) = x \log_2(x)$. It took me a while to understand where your first inequality came from. But I see that it comes from the fact that given $f$ a convex function, $f(\lambda 2r_1 + (1-\lambda)2r_2) \leq \lambda f(2r_1) + (1-\lambda)f(2r_2)$ where $\lambda = 1/2$.